# Расположение компонентов в Java Swing FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Необходимо, чтобы текстовое поле располагалось под меткой, при этом, элементы должны быть плавающими. Как это реализовать в менеджере компоновки FlowLayout?

Comment: Вряд ли это можно сделать при помощи `FlowLayout` я бы посоветовал  разобраться в `GridBagLayout` при помощи него можно сделать любую компоновку. `GridBagLayout` на первый взгляд может показаться сложным, но если понять как с ним работать, то вы поймете что это мощный инструмент для позиционирования компонентов.

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте надеюсь правильно понял Ваш вопрос. Вы хотите соблюдать положение нескольких объектов в макете с плавающей структурой.Подходов масса, как вариант оберните один макет в другой посредством некоторого компонента...вот пример:

```
public class Test extends Applet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Panel p = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(new Label("some string"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(new TextArea("text area"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new Button("first button"));
        add(p);
        add(new Button("second button"));
    }

}
```

Так же не забывайте о классе Canvas с которым можно работать как с отдельным полотном.Ну и почти всемогущий макет `GridBagLayout` как уже писали...